# psycopg2 syntax error because of single quotes in insert command

Tags: python, psycopg2

I'm trying to execute an "insert table" command using psycopg2. I create the command string in a function which returns a string of the following form:

```
create table %s (  %s %s , %s %s , %s %s , %s %s , %s %s , %s %s , %s %s , %s %s , %s %s , %s %s , %s %s , primary key %s );
```

The function also returns a tuple of string variables that I want to use to fill in for the format strings:

```
('games', 'score_loser', 'integer', 'playoffs', 'boolean', 'record_loser', 'integer[]', 'broadcast', 'varchar(20)', 'date', 'date', 'id', 'varchar (30)', 'home_team', 'varchar (50)', 'record_winner', 'integer[]', 'winner', 'varchar (50)', 'loser', 'varchar (50)', 'score_winner', 'integer', 'id')
```

But when I try to execute the command I have the problem that the variables from the tuple are placed into single quotes, which results in a syntax error in psycopg2:

```
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "'games'"
```

LINE 1: create table 'games' (  'score_loser' 'integer' , 'playoffs'...

Can someone tell me what should be done instead?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't do that. From the [Psycopg documentation on query parameters](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#query-parameters):

> Only query values should be bound via this method: it shouldn’t be used to merge table or field names to the query (Psycopg will try quoting the table name as a string value, generating invalid SQL). If you need to generate dynamically SQL queries (for instance choosing dynamically a table name) you can use the facilities provided by the psycopg2.sql module:

```
>>> cur.execute("INSERT INTO %s VALUES (%s)", ('numbers', 10))  # WRONG
>>> cur.execute(                                                # correct
...     SQL("INSERT INTO {} VALUES (%s)").format(Identifier('numbers')),
...     (10,))
```